# I had a shared Google Doc but the person who shared it deleted their account and the doc is gone, is there way to get it back?

Tags: google, google-drive

When the account was deleted all documents they shared with me(months of work) disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  If the account is deleted everything is deleted with it - regardless of whether a document is shared or not.

There is no way to recover the deleted items via Google Docs.